# We know that the earth has charge of -500,000 C experimentally or by equations?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

I don't understand how we get this value and what it means, does it mean that this charge distributed over earth surface so charge density is small? Or it distributed over the volume?

Comment: The fair-weather field is about 100 V/m, maybe that integrated over Earth's surface gives this charge? Calculate it yourself.